# How to return more than one LIKE from MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

SOLVED.

When I do search in my database (through a console) the return shows rows where the word "keywordOne" and "keywordTwo" occurs:

```
SELECT name FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE '%keywordOne&' OR name LIKE '%keywordTwo%';
```

but when I try to run that query from .php code, the return only shows the rows with keywordOne:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows == 0){
   echo "<br>No rows found. ";
} else {
   $how_many = 0;
   echo '<table style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; ">';
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $name = $row['name'];
      echo '<tr><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Found (by name): </td>' . '<td>' . $name . '</td></tr>';
      $how_many = $how_many + 1;
}
echo '</table>';
echo "<br>";
echo "In total: " . $how_many . " rows found.";
```

Why that happened? Or am I printing the rows incorrectly on .php script?

When I run

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name REGEXP 'keywordOne|keywordTwo' ";
```

command, the return on .php script is correct (with both keywords).

What's missing?

Comment: '%keywordOne&' should be '%keywordOne%'

Comment: You are actually right. What a shame!